# Transformers understanding

Tags: keras, nlp, transformer

i have i a big trouble. I don't understand transformers. I understand embedding, rnn's, GAN's, even Attention. But i don't understand transformers. Approximately 2 months ago i decided to avoid usage of transformers, because i found them hard. But i can't anymore avoid transformers. Please, help me. I want to use and understand work of transformers. How can i start to work with them?Past the fact that i want to understand their idea in general, i also want to can write/implement them using keras/tensorflow
Of course i tied to read some tutorials.  But i don't understand them anyway.

Comment: Transformers use many building blocks, like self-attention, layer normalization, residual connections, etc. What exactly don't you understand about transformers? Tutorials like [The illustrated transformer](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) probably do a better job explaining the whole model than we can do here, but we can try to help you understand specific aspects of it if you identify those parts.

Comment: @noe, thank u. I'll read this article and say what i don't understand

Comment: @noe, Does softmax label on photo mean how much the word relate to the first one? https://pasteboard.co/JMvN4Le.png

Comment: Softmax refers to the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)

Comment: The role of the softmax is to normalize the sum up to 1. In the example, you can see that the softmax-normalized values are 0.88 and 0.12, which add up to 1. The result of the softmax is then used as weights for the values, which are then added together.

Comment: @noe, when i asked question about softmax i didn't mean softmax function. But anyway, that's not main trouble and i understood my problem about softmax. I didn't understand decoder side. https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/#the-decoder-side I understand that output from the higher encoder forms K and V vectors for decoder. But i don't understand all that written bellow about decoder. What's going on in the decoder side? And how decoder forms output?

P.S thank u for helping me.

Comment: The decoder is very similar to the encoder, especially at training time. The main differences is that the queries are taken from the target side while keys and values are from the source side, and that the attention is masked to avoid the prediction for time t to be dependent on the tokens at the same and future positions.

Comment: @noe what does decoder receive(as input) 
here? https://habrastorage.org/webt/l6/ry/nl/l6rynlkppwpzjaenv35ipi8vcpq.gif

Comment: At training time, the decoder receives the whole target sentence tokens. At inference time, we don't have the target sentence; instead, we use the model autoregressively: at each decoding step we pass as input the previous predictions, get the prediction for the next token, concatenate it with the previous step input and use it as input for the next step; at the first step of the autoregressive decoding we simply pass as input a sequence with just the special token `<s>`.

Comment: @noe,thank u. At the first step of the autoregressive decoding we simply pass as input a sequence with just the special token <s> Is that sequence (which we pass to decoder at the first step of autoregressive decoding) outputs from encoders? https://pasteboard.co/JMFengd.jpg.

Comment: I understood other things about autoregressive decoding

Comment: The decoder receives both the output of the encoder and the target sequence, either the full sequence at training time or the partial sequence at inference time.

Comment: I added these comments as an answer so that you can upvote it and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the answers to the specific doubts that you pointed out in the comments:

- Transformers use many building blocks, like self-attention, layer normalization, residual connections, etc. Tutorials like [The illustrated transformer](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) are very useful to understand these blocks and how they fit together.
- The role of the softmax is to normalize the sum up to 1. In the example, you can see that the softmax-normalized values are 0.88 and 0.12, which add up to 1. The result of the softmax is then used as weights for the values, which are then added together.
- The decoder is very similar to the encoder, especially at training time. The main differences are that the queries are taken from the target side while keys and values are from the source side and that the attention is masked to avoid the prediction for time t to be dependent on the tokens at the same and future positions.
- The decoder receives both the output of the encoder and the target sequence, either the full sequence at training time or the partial sequence at inference time.
- At training time, the decoder receives the whole target sentence tokens. At inference time, we don't have the target sentence; instead, we use the model autoregressively: at each decoding step we pass as input the previous predictions, get the prediction for the next token, concatenate it with the previous step input and use it as input for the next step; at the first step of the autoregressive decoding we simply pass as input a sequence with just the special token `<s>`.

Comment: how to use autoregressive decoding in the code? I can't find it(at each decoding step we pass as input the previous predictions, get the prediction for the next token, concatenate it with the previous step input and use it as input for the next step;) here
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/transformer_chatbot.ipynb And i also don't understand how authors form tf.data.Dataset. Sorry for my dumb questions. But i've understood how authors have formed tokenized dataset(tokenize_and_filter function)

Comment: thank u for helping me!

Comment: please, check it out. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/100456/vq-gan-understanding
I owe you