# VQ-GAN understanding

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, transformer, gan

I tried to understand how VQ-GAN works, but unfortunately I have not understood it. I tried to read some articles about it and watch a video. I believe a good and simple article will help me. You helped me with [transformers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88823/transformers-understanding). You gave me wonderful link. I know what CNNs, GANs, TRANSFORMERSs, and CLIP are. I somehow understood a bit how VQ-VAE works, but still do not understand some things about it. But I cannot understand how VQ-GAN works. Please, help me to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: It will be better if you walkthrough the paper and mask more specific questions about where you are losing track, that way I could provide clearer answers.

Answer (score 0):

**GANs** are a type of deep learning model that consist of two parts: **a generator network that produces fake images**, and **a discriminator network that tries to distinguish the fake images from real ones**. The **generator** and **discriminator** compete with each other, with the **generator** trying to produce images that the **discriminator** cannot tell apart from real images, and the **discriminator** trying to get better at telling them apart.

**VQ-GAN** is a type of **generative adversarial network (GAN)** that uses a **vector quantization (VQ) mechanism** to improve the *quality and diversity of the generated images*.

In a **VQ-GAN**, the ***generator network uses a vector quantization (VQ) layer to quantize its output into a set of discrete vectors***. This has the effect of forcing the generator to produce images that are more similar to the training data, because the quantization ensures that the generated images are a "nearest neighbor" of the training images in the discrete code space. In other words, the **VQ layer** encourages the generator to produce images that are similar to ones it has seen before, rather than generating completely novel images.

The **VQ-GAN** architecture also includes a learned **"encoder"** network that maps real images to the same discrete code space as the generator. This allows the **discriminator** to learn a distance metric in the discrete code space, which allows it to *better distinguish between real and fake images*.

The ***VQ-GAN architecture is similar to that of a VQ-VAE***, which is a type of generative model that also uses a VQ layer to learn a discrete representation of the data. However, unlike a **VQ-VAE**, a **VQ-GAN** uses a discriminator network to guide the learning process and to provide feedback to the generator on the quality of its generated samples. This allows the **VQ-GAN** to learn a more effective generative model than a **VQ-VAE**, which only uses the **reconstruction error** of the **VQ layer** as a learning signal.

Overall, **VQ-GAN** combines the ***strengths of GANs and VQ-VAE (vector quantized variational autoencoders)*** to produce high-quality images that are similar to the training data. It is a relatively recent development in the field of deep learning, and there is still ongoing research into the best ways to design and train **VQ-GANs**. To learn more about **VQ-GAN**, you can read the original paper by Oord et al., which describes the architecture and provides some experimental results.

---

- [Synopsis: Taming Transformers for High-Resolution Image Synthesis (VQ-GAN & Transformer)](https://towardsai.net/p/deep-learning/synopsis-taming-transformers-for-high-resolution-image-synthesis-vq-gan-transformer)
- [The Illustrated VQGAN](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2021/08/08/clip-vqgan/)